# Sharing CherryPy's BackgroundTaskQueue object between request handlers

Tags: python, cherrypy, object-sharing

I'm using cherrypy to build a web service. I came across the [BackgroundTaskQueue](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/BackgroundTaskQueue) plugin and I want to use it to handle specific time-consuming operations on a separate thread.

The documentation states the usage should be like the following:

```
import cherrypy
from complicated_logging import log

bgtask = BackgroundTaskQueue(cherrypy.engine)
bgtask.subscribe()

class Root(object):

    def index(self):
        bgtask.put(log, "index was called", ip=cherrypy.request.remote.ip))
        return "Hello, world!"
    index.exposed = True
```

But, IMHO, using the bgtask object like this isn't very elegant. I would like handlers from other python modules to use this object too.

Is there a way to subscribe this plugin once, and then "share" the bgtask object among other handlers (like, for example saving it it in the `cherrypy.request`)?

How is this done? Does this require writing a cherrypy tool?

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
queue = BackgroundTaskQueue(cherrypy.engine)
```

in a separate file named, for instance, *tasks.py*. This way you create module *tasks*.
Now you can '*import tasks*' in other modules and *queue* is a single instance

For example, in a file called *test.py*:

```
import tasks
def test(): print('works!')
tasks.queue.put(log, test)
```